# Rutas al incluir un archivo en php

Tags: php, rutas

Muy buenas noches caballeros, tengo una pregunta acerca de rutas, lo que sucede es que tengo una imagen de **logo** en un archivo de entrada a mi **aplicación** en otras palabras un **login**,sucede que cuando estoy validando dicho **login** lo requiero y cuando acaba la validación esta misma esta en otra carpeta y no carga la imagen, quisiera saber si existe alguna técnica o método que permita no perder la **url** de la cual estoy haciendo inclusión de mi archivo original?

**Ejemplo:**
Este es el ejemplo corto se me esta perdiendo la ruta de la imagen
**logo** y por ende los estilos.

```
introducir el código aquí
   <form action="views/includes/Validacion.php" method="POST" >
       <img src="content/img/logo.png" alt="Imagen del logo" class="imagen">
   </form>
```

Este es el archivo al cual mando los datos desde el formulario y por el cual valido, y llamo la vista que me mando los datos.

```
introducir el código aquí

 if($user->userExists($userForm, $passForm)){
        echo "Usuario validado";
    }else{
        $errorLogin = 'Nombre de usuario y/o password es incorrecto';
        include_once('../../index.php');    
    }
```

En mi login todo carga perfecto, pero la imagen se pierde porque no encuentra la ruta del directorio dentro de la **validación** que le especifique en el login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensaya poner la ruta de la imagen relativa a la raiz de tu web... que estoy suponiendo que es `/content/img/logo.png` (Le puse un `/` al inicio)...

Si la ruta de la imagen es solo "content/img/logo.png", esta será relativa al archivo que hayas cargado, por eso cuando vas a views/include/validacion.php ya no la encuentra.

Si le agregas el / al inicio siempre sera relativo al root de tu web (en el server).

O sea:

```
<form action="views/includes/Validacion.php" method="POST" >
    <img src="/content/img/logo.png" alt="Imagen del logo" class="imagen">
</form>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias pipe, como tu dijiste con rutas absolutas y funciono pero tuve que mover el archivo de index porque no se encontraba en la raíz de mi proyecto,sino en una carpeta llamada public, ahora todo esta funcionando correctamente mi gran amigo, muchísimas gracias por haberme ayudado